# Keras loss function using also input data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, loss-function

I have the following problem:

I have a sequential NN for doing regression for a specific problem. My input is a 5-D array, my output a 6-D array. My normal loss function is just the MSE on the difference (y_pred - y_true).

Now, I have this property: the 1st element of the output vector (i.e y_pred[:,0]), multiplied with the 1st element of the input vector (i.e x[:,0]) is bounded from above by a constant K.
Thus, I need to add a penalty to my loss function, something like:
(1/n) * || y_pred[:,0] * x[:,0] - K ||.

I created my wrapper for custom loss function in order to be able to use the input values:

```
def custom_loss_wrapper(input_train):
   def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
       return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) + K.mean(K.square(input_train))
   return custom_loss
```

Here, I just used the MSE on the input for semplicity, but the following outcome is the same!

The problem is that, when I try to insert computation with input_train, during the fitting of the model I get this error:

> Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [< tf.Tensor 'input_22:0' shape=(None, 5) dtype=float32 >]

Now, I found out that I can use the following to not have this problem:

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

But if I do this, the error becomes:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (truediv_65:0) to a numpy array.

SO, what I could do to use my custom loss function ?

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using? Also, are you using Keras or tf.keras?

Comment: I'm using Tensorflow 2.0.0. and tf.keras